How can I set light/dark theme with Fast Web Components?
I am using https://www.fast.design/docs/components/checkbox
in a simple HTML page, but it seems that the default theme is dark ... so "white text" on a "white background" : it's not readable.
How can I change this weird behaviour? (designsystem, but how to ? docs are not simple).


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@microsoft/fast-components/dist/fast-components.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <fieldset>
    <fast-checkbox checked>Apple</fast-checkbox>
    <fast-checkbox checked>Banana</fast-checkbox>
  </fieldset>
</body>

</html>




Wow those docs are terrible  Your best bet may be to simply use CSS.
fast-checkbox::part(label) {
color: red; /* Change the color to whatever you desire */
    }



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@microsoft/fast-components/dist/fast-components.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    fast-checkbox::part(label) {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <fieldset>
    <fast-checkbox checked>Apple</fast-checkbox>
    <fast-checkbox checked>Banana</fast-checkbox>
  </fieldset>
</body>

</html>



